# eclipse, How to make eclipse bar in one line

Tags: eclipse

I don't know what happend and my eclipse bar goes into 2 line

[image]

How can I move it into a line ? I tried to close perspective and open it again but It didn't solve it .

How can I make them in one line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective.

Remove what you consider useless and when there's enough space, Eclipse will merge the bar into one. It happened here with mine, right now, but I'm using Ubuntu. It should work with any OS, though.

Example when there's not enough space:
[image: Not enough space example]

Example when there is space:
[image]